# jQuery toggleClass() something not right

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

So I'm currently working on a responsive navigation menu. I've created them before but for some reason cannot get this one to work! maybe I'm looking over something, can anyone have a look and tell me what I'm overlooking? haha

If I make the following change:

```
.show {
   display: block; !important
}
```

I can achieve the drop down without it quickly hiding itself again, but have achieved it before without having to use !important.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b1jeur0s/)

Answer (score 3):

Avoid the media query overriding the drop down show class:
- [Working Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/b1jeur0s/1/)

```
#nav-dropdown ul.show {
  display:block;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

This was the problem I could see.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

  #nav-dropdown ul {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Having "#nav-dropdown ul.show" CSS fixed the issue as ID's are unique and takes preference over classes.

Comment: No problem, happy to help!